# How to save all users "chat id"-s inside database(telegram bot) node

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

i want to store "chat id"-s of all users of my telegram bot and send notification/message to them. How can i implement it. im using node.js

Answer (score 0):

bot api doesn't allow to get ids of previous users - you just get an id when somebody writes to a bot, so you should store ids in realtime

for example, there is a middleware for telegraf.js to store users in mongo: https://www.npmjs.com/package/telegraf-mongodb-middleware

at all there are many different approaches which may be more comfortable to you for either storing or reading from - you can use a file, redis, sql databases (sqlite would be a good option), etc.